# Grouping media queries?

Tags: html, css

What is the way to group media queries for multiple devices of different widths?
For example something like this -

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px),
@media screen and (max-width: 760px),
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px)
{

}
```

Comment: why did you declined your accepted answer ?! didn`t it help you ?!

Comment: @Afshin, no it did not

Comment: hey dude, the code I provided is correct, but your browser does not support `device-aspect-ratio` for sure. Have a look at this page to see if your browser supports it or not:

http://cssmediaqueries.com/overview.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
@media only screen 
    and (max-width:480px)
    and (device-aspect-ratio: 2/3)
    and (device-aspect-ratio: 40/71)
    and (device-aspect-ratio: 667/375)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use the following?

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px) 
              and (device-aspect-ratio: 2/3)
              and (device-aspect-ratio: 40/71)
              and (device-aspect-ratio: 667/375)
{
}
```